# A mass attached to a spring is allowed to fall. Why is it's lowest point where the work done by gravity equals the work done by the spring?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, spring

#### The Problem

This is the problem that originally sparked my interest:

A spring of spring constant $k = 8.75 \frac{\text{N}}{\text{m}}$ is hung vertically from a rigid support. A mass of $0.500 \text{kg}$ is placed on the end of the spring and supported by hand at a point so that the displacement of the spring is $0.250 \text{m}$. The mass is suddenly released and allowed to fall. At the lowest point of the mass, what is the displacement of the spring from its equilibrium position?

#### The Solution

I thought about this problem, and I'll explain my thought process after the solution, but I ended up ultimately coming across this solution:

(Edit: I'm guessing the solution establishes that the positive $x$ axis is South)

Here is a diagram of the situation: https://ibb.co/fGjdRxs

$$
\begin{align*}
&\text{In order to solve this problem, we have to relate the work done by gravity} \\ 
&\text{with the work done by the spring. Let's use two displacements:} \\
&\text{Let $x_1$ be the original displacement.}\\
&\text{Let $x_2$ be the final displacement.} \\
&\text{The mass will come to rest once the work done by the spring is the same} \\
&\text{as the work done by gravity.} \\
&W_g = mgh = mg(x_2 - x_1) \\
&W_s = \frac{1}{2}kx^2 = \frac{1}{2}k(x_2^2-x_1^2) \\
&W_g = W_s \\
&x_1 = 0.25 \text{m} \\
&mg(x_2 - x_1) = \frac{1}{2}k(x_2^2-x_1^2) \\
&0.5 \text{kg} \cdot9.8\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}^2} \cdot(x_2 - 0.25 \text{m}) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 8.75\frac{\text{N}}{\text{m}} \cdot (x_2^2 - (0.25\text{m})^2) \\
&x_2 = \{0.25\text{m}, 0.87\text{m}\} \\
&\text{$0.25\text{m}$ is the original displacement, therefore the solution displacement is $0.87\text{m}$.}
\end{align*}
$$

This solution does arrive at the correct answer, but I don't quite understand it conceptually.

#### My Thought Process

I would assume that the mass comes to a stop when the force pulling it down (gravity) equals the force pulling it up (the spring), NOT when the work having been done is the same.

I would assume that the forces acting on the mass can be different even if the total work done by both factors is the same. Shouldn't this problem instead be solved by calculating when the forces are equal?

If not, what's the right way to understand this conceptually? **Why does the mass come to a stop when the work done by gravity and the spring are equal?**

Comment: Your solution is nonsense, you start displacing your spring 0.25m upwards (I assume upwards since you never specified how you defined your coordinate system) and then the spring elongates up to 0.87m. There is some inconsistence, you don't have enough work for the mass being raised without another intervention of the hand

Comment: Even if it was downwards, the spring would go up because always you displace an spring with respect to the equilibrium point

Comment: @Pizzaguy07 The spring is hung vertically from a rigid support, the equilibrium position of the end of the spring is where the displacement is 0.

Comment: But explain using your common sense how you expect if the initial condition says that the spring is displaced .25m then it will tend to go up to .87m instead of seeking the equilibrium point

Comment: @Pizzaguy07 It would look like this: https://ibb.co/GxGWndt

Comment: But $x$ is a coordinate, is the position of the mass, not a variable that measures the length of the spring. You set it at zero when the mass is in a position such that the spring is in equilibrium. So, your X2 has to be negative

Comment: And if your initial speed is zero and you have no energy losses, then the spring will go to -0.25m. It has to oscillate symmetrically

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether or not the displacement is positive or negative, because you would arrive at the same answer either way as we're technically calculating the difference between the two positions. The problem does not talk about oscillation. It only asks: on the initial drop, what's the lowest point of the mass?

Comment: Your problem is confusing, about which displacement are you talking about? The displacement of the spring wrt the equilibrium position of the mass, of the displacement wrt the position where the length of spring it's its natural length? That would clarify. And NO, the sign DOES care because it tells you if the mass is up or down the equilibrium position of the system

Comment: @Pizzaguy07 Here is a better diagram: https://ibb.co/fGjdRxs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would assume that the mass comes to a stop when the force pulling it
> down (gravity) equals the force pulling it up (the spring)

At this point the net force is zero, and the mass has zero acceleration, not (necessarily) zero velocity.

> If not, what's the right way to understand this conceptually? Why does
> the mass come to a stop when the work done by gravity and the spring
> are equal?

According to the problem, both the initial and final velocity are zero. So, there is no change in the kinetic energy. And we know that the work done by the net force equals the change of kinetic energy. So the net work is zero. Or, if we decompose it in the 2 acting forces: the work from the spring must be equal in modulus to the work from gravity (but with opposing signs).

Comment: Thank you. This perfectly explains what I was looking for conceptually.

Answer (score 1):

(I see the correct answer posted. But I'll post this anyway because I already wrote it, so why not :D)

The mass wouldn't come to a stop when the forces are equal. If there is no net force, it only means that the block's acceleration at that moment is zero. A zero acceleration does **not** imply zero velocity.

Now on why it comes to a stop when the works are equal, note that the initial and final kinetic energy of the mass are equal (zero). By work energy theorem, Change in its kinetic energy can be written as
$$\Delta E_k = W_{grav} + W_{spring}=0$$
Work done on the block by gravitational force:
$$W_{grav} = mg (x_2 - x_1)$$
And work done by spring force would be
$$W_{spring} = -\frac{1}{2} k(x_2^2 - x_1^2)$$
Negative, as spring force is opposite to the motion here. Combining the two lead the equation you have.